# Is there any script that allows to do a fft from an USB microphone in real time in python?

Tags: python, usb, fft, microphone, tcpsocket

I am working with a raspberry pi 3B and an USB microphone. I want to do a fft in real time and obtaint values like what audio level there is in what frequency and after obtain these data, put an alarm level to detect when in a frequency the audio level is too high. After that, send the alarm message via tcp to a remote computer.

I prefer to use a python script but any other language is accepted. It has to be real time audio, not recorded one.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to make a recording anyway of a short time period, e.g. using pyaudio.
Then you can use any of the numpy.fft functions and check all the bins against your threshold.